# How to show accept terms and conditions in MAC build after click on application dmg file

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge, electronic-signature

I am using Electron Builder to create a build for my app. I want an accept terms and condition window will show with checkbox and if user select checkbox and click on continue only then app will get installed otherwise exit the installation.How can i do it in electornjs.
For windows you can easily do this by adding this

```
"nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "license": "LICENSE.txt", // <- Put your license name here.
    },
```

how can we do this similar thing in mac?